# Select all the records of the previous month in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, datetime

I have a small requirement in my project:

I want to `fetch all the records of the previous month from the database.`

The `structure of the table` is as follows:

```
id   clientid     task   date     
1    1            1      01.Feb.2011 12:13
2    1            1      05.Feb.2011 15:22
3    1            0      09.Feb.2011 14:17
4    2            1      11.Feb.2011 19:53
5    1            0      19.Feb.2011 14:27
6    2            1      23.Feb.2011 09:53
7    1            0      01.Mar.2011 14:17
8    2            1      01.Mar.2011 19:53
9    1            0      03.Mar.2011 14:67
10   2            1      03.Mar.2011 09:53
.....................
```

Here I want to `fetch` all the `records` of the `previous month` of a `particular client` in `Zend Framework.`

For Example : If I want `client 1` records then It should show me records : `1,2,3 and 5.`

Please Suggest some code, or link that helps me......

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the date column is a [DateTime column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), I'd try with something like

```
$select->from('tablename')
       ->where('MONTH(date) = ?', date('n', strtotime('last month')))
       ->where('YEAR(date) = ?', date('Y'))
       ->where('clientid = ?', $clientId)
;
```

*Note: untested and likely needs tweaking but it's the general direction*

This would fetch all rows from tablename where the month is the last month and year is the current year and your clientId is the selected clientId. So the query should become something like

```
SELECT * from tablename 
    WHERE MONTH(date) = 2 
      AND YEAR(date) = 2011
      AND clientid = 1;
```

You could also put the calculation for last month and current year directly into the query, e.g. using the [appropriate MySql functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) for this instead of calculating them with PHP. This might be more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first day of the current month using PHP:

```
$this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), 1, date("Y"));
$previous_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, 1, date("Y"));
```

Then you simply pass this date as a parameter of your query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date >= ? AND date < ? and client_id = 1
```

where you replace the ? respectively by '$previous_month' and '$this_month'

Comment: This would also return records older than 1 month ago.

Answer (score 1):

If your `date` field is of the type `Datetime` you can use the date specific functions in MySQL to do this. Simply construct your statement with `Zend_Db_Expr` when using database functions.

Answer (score 1):

My Zend_Db skill is a bit rusty, but I think the following does what you want:

```
$select->from('tablename')
           ->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('MONTH(`date`) =  MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))'))
           ->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('YEAR(`date`) = IF(MONTH(NOW()) = 1, YEAR(NOW()) - 1, YEAR(NOW()))'))
           ->where('clientid = ?', $clientId)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQL DATE_SUB and INTERVAL function like:

```
select * from table where `date` >=  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month)
```

In ZF1 you can write something like:

```
$select->from('tablename')
 ->where( 'date >=  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month)');
```